# Canvas object always draw behind other object

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Im using a HTML Canvas to draw a graph. I have horizontal lines and labels for each line. But the labels always appear behind the lines, even though they are draw second. The code is:

```
function paintGrid(canvas, context) {

    var xSegment = 200 / 5,
        ySegment = 200 / 5;

    var color = '#EEE';

    // DRAW GRID 
    context.fillStyle = color;
    context.strokeStyle = color;
    context.lineWidth = 5;

    for (var y = 0; y < 5; y++) {
        context.moveTo(0, (y * ySegment));
        context.lineTo(200, (y * ySegment));
        context.stroke();
    }


    // LABELS
    context.font = "9pt Arial";
    context.fillStyle = '#000';

    var ySeg = canvas.height / 5;
    var xSeg = canvas.width / 5;
    var yLabel, xLabel, zeroLabel;

    for (var y = 1; y < 5; y++) {

        yLabel = (ySegment * y).toFixed(1);

        context.fillText(yLabel, 5, (canvas.height - (ySeg * y)));
        context.stroke();
    }
}
```

The fiddle is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/oecv7o30/1/).

As you can see, the labels are behind the lines. It doesnt matter what order I draw, the lines first or the labels first, they always appear behind. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you're calling `stroke` again. `stroke` will draw the current path, which you generated in your first `for` loop. To see what I mean, move `context.stroke()` outside of the `for` loop. You'll get the lines you want.

```
for (var y = 0; y < 5; y++) {
    context.moveTo(0, (y * ySegment));
    context.lineTo(200, (y * ySegment));
    // context.stroke();
}
context.stroke();
```

Likewise, you don't need to call `stroke()` after `fillText`. Remove that entirely from your second loop.

```
for (var y = 1; y < 5; y++) {
    yLabel = (ySegment * y).toFixed(1);
    context.fillText(yLabel, 5, (canvas.height - (ySeg * y)));
}
```

Note: if you intend to call this multiple times, it would be wise to use [`beginPath`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/beginPath) to start a new path and avoid re-drawing any old paths.

```
context.beginPath();
for (var y = 0; y < 5; y++) {
    context.moveTo(0, (y * ySegment));
    context.lineTo(200, (y * ySegment));
    // context.stroke();
}
context.stroke();
```